# Passing a parameter into AWS CLI command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to set tags on an EC2 instance with the following call from a python script where I am passing in a variable `instanceId` as the resource to add the tags on:

```
subprocess.call('aws ec2 create-tags --resources $instanceId --tags "Key=somekey, Value=someval"')
```

But I get this error:

```
An error occurred (MissingParameter) when calling the CreateTags operation: The request must contain the parameter resourceIdSet
255
```

However, when I print out `instanceId`, I see the correct id of the instance so there must be something wrong with the way I am passing in the variable. Is there a different convention for this?

Comment: Are you running an old version of the AWS CLI tool? Run `aws --version` to see what version you have installed.

Comment: As per the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module, you should call `subprocess.call()` with list of params

Comment: This error can appear if you passed an invalid or missing resourceId to the --resources option, such as in code where you have it as a variable and it does not expand. It may be misleading as it says resourceIdSet. As mentioned around here, check that the variable is expanding or passed between scopes.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `$instanceId` in your AWS CLI command will end up being a shell variable, and won't be substituted from your Python code.

So, if `$instanceId` is a Python variable, you may need to do something like:

```
subprocess.call('aws ec2 create-tags --resources ' + $instanceId  + ' --tags "Key=somekey, Value=someval"')
```

Note: I am not a Python developer, so this is a stab in the dark.